# Vim will not quit sometimes

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

Vim will not quit sometimes (I have saved session in which vim wont quit) after writing **:q**, terminal just freezes (same with gVim), I cannot do anything except force closing the terminal or window (in gVim).

#### Log reading attempt (nothing interesting)

I tried to run vim with log file enabled

```
~ vim -V9myVimLog
```

when I quit nothing interesting written to log, but when I close terminal (after vim has frozen) - last line says *Testing the X display failed*.

#### Without plugins (works)

I tried running **~ vim -u NONE**, and then I loaded a session (which always fails to quit), and it worked ok - vim quitted. I have lots of vim plugins and I don't want to go over each one of them. (I have to modify vimrc then run +BundleInstall)

What can I do? How should I debug this? How can I identify plugin which is root of the cause?

edit:

#### Tern for vim

Its [tren_for_vim](https://github.com/marijnh/tern_for_vim)s fault. Any ideas?

Comment: `I have lots of vim plugins and I don't want to go over each one of them.` - Tough because _one of them_ is responsible for the problem =). Check which of them implement a `bufwritepost` - as that's probably where the problem is. Here's a [similar problem, affecting syntastic](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic/issues/162).

Comment: @AD7six I was also asking how to identify a plugin going over 20 plugins takes some time. So I found which plugin is causing this, now I have to figure how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

This looks a problem with tern-for-vim plugin . I installed the same plugin and I am facing some issues from time to time .